# Accessing InnerClass Objects through OuterClass Objects

Tags: java, android, json

I have a custom class of Flight and Inner Class of Fare

```
public class Flight {
    private String airlineCode;
    private String airlineClass;
    private String originCode;
    private String destinationCode;
    private String departureTime;
    private String ArrivalTime;

    public Flight (String originCode,String destinationCode,String departureTime,String arrivalTime,
                   String airlineCode, String airlineClass){
        this.originCode=originCode;
        this.destinationCode=destinationCode;
        this.departureTime=departureTime;
        this.ArrivalTime=arrivalTime;
        this.airlineCode=airlineCode;
        this.airlineClass=airlineClass;

    }

    public String getAirlineCode() {
        return airlineCode;
    }

    public void setAirlineCode(String airlineCode) {
        this.airlineCode = airlineCode;
    }

    public String getAirlineClass() {
        return airlineClass;
    }

    public void setAirlineClass(String airlineClass) {
        this.airlineClass = airlineClass;
    }

    public String getOriginCode() {
        return originCode;
    }

    public void setOriginCode(String originCode) {
        this.originCode = originCode;
    }

    public String getDestinationCode() {
        return destinationCode;
    }

    public void setDestinationCode(String destinationCode) {
        this.destinationCode = destinationCode;
    }

    public String getDepartureTime() {
        return departureTime;
    }

    public void setDepartureTime(String departureTime) {
        this.departureTime = departureTime;
    }

    public String getArrivalTime() {
        return ArrivalTime;
    }

    public void setArrivalTime(String arrivalTime) {
        ArrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    }

    //Inner Class
    class Fare{
        private String providerId;
        private String fare;

        public Fare(String providerId,String fare){
            this.providerId=providerId;
            this.fare=fare;
        }

        public String getProviderId() {
            return providerId;
        }

        public String getFare() {
            return fare;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a sample JSON which I have to traverse and Put the Value inside that custom class. Following is a short sample of JSON.

```
{
  "flights": [
    {
      "originCode": "DEL",
      "destinationCode": "BOM",
      "departureTime": 1396614600000,
      "arrivalTime": 1396625400000,
      "fares": [
        {
          "providerId": 1,
          "fare": 11500
        },
        {
          "providerId": 2,
          "fare": 10500
        }
      ],
      "airlineCode": "G8",
      "class": "Business"
    },
    {
      "originCode": "DEL",
      "destinationCode": "BOM",
      "departureTime": 1396616400000,
      "arrivalTime": 1396623600000,
      "fares": [
        {
          "providerId": 1,
          "fare": 14400
        },
        {
          "providerId": 3,
          "fare": 14000
        }
      ],
      "airlineCode": "AI",
      "class": "Business"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am parsing and creating the ArrayList like this

```
public static final ArrayList<Flight> extractdata(String jsonResponse) {
        ArrayList<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<Flight>();

        try {
            JSONObject rootobject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

            JSONArray flight = rootobject.getJSONArray("flights");

            for (int i = 0; i < flight.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject arrayObject = flight.getJSONObject(i);

                String originCode = arrayObject.getString("originCode");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"originalcode"+  originCode);
                String destinationCode = arrayObject.getString("destinationCode");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"destinationcode"+  destinationCode);
                String departureTime = arrayObject.getString("departureTime");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"departuretime"+  departureTime);
                String arrivalTime = arrayObject.getString("arrivalTime");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"arrivaltime"+  arrivalTime);
                String airlineCode = arrayObject.getString("airlineCode");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"airlinecode"+  airlineCode);
                String airlineClass = arrayObject.getString("class");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"class"+  airlineClass);
                Long eTime = Long.parseLong(arrivalTime);
                Date dateObject = new Date(eTime);
                Long dTime = Long.parseLong(departureTime);
                Date dateObject2 = new Date(dTime);
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH mm ");
                String arrival = dateFormat.format(dateObject);
                String depart = dateFormat.format(dateObject2);
                JSONArray arrayFare=arrayObject.getJSONArray("fares");

                String providerId;
                String fare;
                int number=arrayFare.length();
                Flight flightObject=new Flight(originCode,destinationCode,depart,arrival,airlineCode,airlineClass);
                for (int j=0;j<arrayFare.length();j++){
                    JSONObject arrayFareObject=arrayFare.getJSONObject(j);
                    providerId=arrayFareObject.getString("providerId");
                    fare=arrayFareObject.getString("fare");
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"providerId & fare :"+providerId+" "+fare);
                    Flight.Fare fareObject[]= new Flight.Fare[number];
                    fareObject[j]=flightObject.new Fare(providerId,fare);
                }
                flights.add(flightObject);   
            }      
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "problem parsing jsone", e);
        }
        return flights;    
    }
```

Now I need to access the InnerClass Objects for whichever Flight Object is   clicked. How do I do that. I am not able to access those objects.

I am trying like this.

```
public  void updateUi(final ArrayList<Flight> flights1)
{

    final FlightAdapter flightAdapter=new FlightAdapter(this,flights1);
    ListView flightlistview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    flightlistview.setAdapter(flightAdapter);
    flightlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Flight flight=flightAdapter.getItem(position);
            Intent fareintent=new Intent(FlightSearchActivity.this,FareActivity.class);
            startActivity(fareintent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need an object of `Fare` as a property of `Flight` class. Get and set this property with the data.

Comment: @PrerakSola If you can just give an example to clear my doubt, it will help a lot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Fare object for your flight class.

If you do this, just creates an object of type Fare with no connection to a particular Flight Object.

```
Flight.Fare fareObject[]= new Flight.Fare[number];
fareObject[j]=flightObject.new Fare(providerId,fare);
```

Instead, declare Fare object along with other variables in your Fligt class:

```
...
private String destinationCode;
private String departureTime;
private String ArrivalTime;
Fare fare;
```

Edit: Add an array of Fares for multiple fares of a flight

```
..
ArrayList<Fare> fares;
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood your point. but since the fare can be Dynamic, I had to take  List<Fare> fare;

But main doubt was to access Inner Objects through Outer Objects, there are no direct way to do it then?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be, since each flight going to have many fares from different airlines. You can have an ArrayList of Fares as the property for each flight.

```
List<Fare> fares
```

Then while reading the json response you can read and create individual Fare class instance and add these instance to fares list. And once you done adding all the fares of individual flight to list, set this list as fares property of Flight instance.

```
List<Fare>fares=new ArrayList<Fare>();
//This code should be in a loop so you can add all the fares to the ArrayList

Fare f=new Fare();
f.setProviderId("AI");
f.setFare("12000");

fares.add(f);
```

Now add the fares list to Flight instance

`flight.setFares(fares)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. So there are no way I can directly access InnerObjects through Outer Objects?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `Flight` class as:

```
public class Flight {
    private String airlineCode;
    private String airlineClass;
    private String originCode;
    private String destinationCode;
    private String departureTime;
    private String ArrivalTime;
    private List<Fare> fares;

    public Flight (String originCode,String destinationCode,String departureTime,String arrivalTime, String airlineCode, String airlineClass, List<Fare> fares){
        this.originCode=originCode;
        this.destinationCode=destinationCode;
        this.departureTime=departureTime;
        this.ArrivalTime=arrivalTime;
        this.airlineCode=airlineCode;
        this.airlineClass=airlineClass;
        this.fares = fares;
    }
    ... //Other getters and setters

    public List<Fare> getFares() {
        return fares;
    }

    public void setFares(List<Fare> fares) {
        this.fares = fares;
    }

    ... //Inner class code
}
```

Now in your `extractdata` method,

```
public static final ArrayList<Flight> extractdata(String jsonResponse) {
        ArrayList<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<Flight>();

        try {
            JSONObject rootobject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

            JSONArray flight = rootobject.getJSONArray("flights");

            for (int i = 0; i < flight.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject arrayObject = flight.getJSONObject(i);

                String originCode = arrayObject.getString("originCode");
                String destinationCode = arrayObject.getString("destinationCode");
                String departureTime = arrayObject.getString("departureTime");
                String arrivalTime = arrayObject.getString("arrivalTime");
                String airlineCode = arrayObject.getString("airlineCode");
                String airlineClass = arrayObject.getString("class");
                Long eTime = Long.parseLong(arrivalTime);
                Date dateObject = new Date(eTime);
                Long dTime = Long.parseLong(departureTime);
                Date dateObject2 = new Date(dTime);
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH mm ");
                String arrival = dateFormat.format(dateObject);
                String depart = dateFormat.format(dateObject2);
                JSONArray arrayFare = arrayObject.getJSONArray("fares");

                List<Fare>fares=new ArrayList<Fare>();

                for (int j=0;j<arrayFare.length();j++){
                    JSONObject arrayFareObject = arrayFare.getJSONObject(j);
                    String providerId = arrayFareObject.getString("providerId");
                    String fare = arrayFareObject.getString("fare");
                    Flight.Fare fareObject = new Flight.Fare(providerId, fare);
                    fares.add(fareObject);
                }
                Flight flightObject = new Flight(originCode, destinationCode, depart, arrival, airlineCode, airlineClass, fares);
                flights.add(flightObject);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "problem parsing jsone", e);
        }
        return flights;    
    }
```

Now in your `updateUi` function, you can get the `fares`by calling `getFares` method:

```
public  void updateUi(final ArrayList<Flight> flights1) {

    final FlightAdapter flightAdapter = new FlightAdapter(this,flights1);
    ListView flightlistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    flightlistview.setAdapter(flightAdapter);
    flightlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Flight flight = flightAdapter.getItem(position);
            List<Fare> fares = flight.getFares();  //This will have all the fares.
            Intent fareintent = new Intent(FlightSearchActivity.this,FareActivity.class);

            startActivity(fareintent);

        }
    });
}
```

**Warning:** I have not tested this code, but it should be something similar to these.